# User Interaction is unavailable while mapkit.setRegion is set

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, user-interaction

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapKitView: MKMapView!
    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        mapKitView.delegate = self
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: locations[0].coordinate.latitude, longitude: locations[0].coordinate.longitude)
        let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.001, longitudeDelta: 0.001)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: span)
        mapKitView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    } 
    
    
}
```

`mapKitView.setRegion(region, animated: true)` is blocking User Interaction in mapkit and I can't zooming, scrolling and rotating

Comment: Every time the location updates you reset the region. So this will make user interaction difficult. If you want allow user interaction don't keep resetting the region.

Answer (score 0):

It seems from the code that you are trying to keep the map centered on the user's location.
To do this while preserving user interaction it's better to delete the line:

```swift
mapKitView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
```

and instead set the `userTrachingMode` property on `mapKitView` to `.follow` or `.followWithHeading`.

with this, the map's visible region will follow the user as the location updates.

Here's the documentation of the `userTrackingMode` property on `MKMapView`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapview/1616208-usertrackingmode